# Website Mobile Issue - Viewport

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I have just launched my website http://www.connorgraham.com.au and am having mobile viewing issues. Prior to launch, everything was working and looking perfect, however I have just realised that on mobile, you are able to scroll to the right to show a white bar that covers 20% or so of an iPhone screen. The website should be full width and you shouldn't be able to scroll to the right. I believe there is some kind of viewport issue, however I am unsure.

I would appreciate any help, and am happy to provide any of my code if it would help solve the issue.

Comment: I checked out your site, but I am not sure what you are referring to when you say the white bar that covers 20%. I even viewed on my iphone 6+ and still couldn't find the issue. Could you provide some more details.

Comment: I have loaded the website on an iphone. On the initial load, the website looks fine, however when you swipe left, the page reveals a white bar for some reason as if the page size is larger than the iphone screen. I can provide images if you would like.

Comment: please do. I have iphone 6+ and the site fits fine on my phone. What version of iphone are you using? Also, what page on your site are you talking about? I am looking at the home page.

Comment: I have taken screenshots through the viewport render in chrome. 

When you first load the page, it looks like this: http://connorgraham.com.au/first.png

After swiping left, it looks like this: http://connorgraham.com.au/second.png

You can view this if you have chrome, right click the page and inspect element, then click the mobile icon in the top left

Comment: okay i found the problem. The logo is not responsive, so as the screen shrinks in size the menu icon drops to the next line when it runs out of room. Let me fool around with this and I will provide you with some code here soon to fix the issue

Comment: see my answer below. You need to adjust footer and header logo size at mobile view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im hoping you have access to the css files. You need to change the top logo and bottom logo widths using media queries. Right now there is a media query for the top logo set at 900px. This needs to be changed:

```
@media (max-width: 399px) {

   .mobile-logo {
   width: 200px;
   float: left;
   }

   .footer img {
  width: 150px;
  }
} 

@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 900px) {
   .mobile-logo {
   width: 300px;
   float: left;
   }
}
```

EDIT: I changed media query to 399px

EDIT: I made the header logo 50px wider (now it is 200px instead of 150px) in the small query

Also, I would change the meta view port to the this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

From my experience it is a bad idea to prevent scaling. This sets the initial scale to 1 and if people want to pinch and zoom they can. This is ideal because you do not always know what the user likes, or if they have a medical condition/disability.

Comment: I adjusted the first media query to 399px instead of 400px. Also, if you want you can make the top logo slightly larger in width, say  200px and see

Comment: Perfect! I couldn't thank you more, you have solved my issue perfectly! I originally had your suggested meta viewport settings, however someone else suggested that changing it to what I had would solve the problem which it did not. I have reverted it back to your suggestions which is great! The site is looking great now and works perfectly for mobile, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that worked! The other meta viewport that was provided is not wrong it just depends on your application and situation. If you need to prevent people from scaling then what they provided is perfect for that. When it comes to a regular website like what you have then I recommend allowing people the option to pinch and zoom.

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified that. There are risks obviously to doing it that way. However, I really don't like the way my sites behave when a user starts zooming in ridiculously far and the menu starts squishing in weird ways.

Comment: @xboxremote - I agree with you completely. There are times when you don't want it. When I first started responsive design I would prevent scaling, but then sometimes I noticed when examining my own sites I tried to zoom in and couldn't! lol. But you can set the scale to a specific amoiunt, for instance instead of setting maximum-scale=1.0  you could say maximum-scale=1.5 or even 2.0. This limits the user ability to zoom way in but still allows them to zoom in some if they need to

Comment: That's a very good point that I'll have to play around with. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

This should disable zoom and will prevent the issue (at least what I think the issue is).

EDIT:

As Charlie pointed out, there is a risk to completely disabling scaling, and a better alternative is to set it to a particular max value so users can still zoom some. This is particularly important for people with disabilities who may be trying to view your site.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added this to the website, however nothing seems to have changed.